# Jacoco .exec coverage file generated separately. How to import into sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

We have an integration test framework complete separate from our application. I can instrument the jvm and produce the jacoco coverage .exec file. But how to import into sonar?

Note the other answers here talk about runnning with ant/gradle/maven as part of the build. In this case, that doesn't work. The tests don't run as a part of a "build"... how can we integrate this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the ANT/Maven/Gradle Sonar task to see if it imports your jacoco exec file? The ANT task - and I assume the others too - allow you to define the sonar.jacoco.reportPath property to tell sonar where your Jacoco exec file is. It should then find the file and send it to your Sonarqube installation.

You should consider that not all work needs to be done by the same tool. For example, suppose you have a folder with the source code and tests. You can use one tool to build the application, a different tool to run unit tests and another different tool to run integration tests all producing output within the source code/tests folder. You can then use ANT (or Maven/Gradle) to send the output to Sonarqube by configuring the appropriate properties to identify the report files.